# Missing logs from heroku pgbackups addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, logging, heroku, backup

I have deployed Rails app to Heroku. App uses PostgreSQL for data management. It works fine locally. I am searching for a way to push my local PostgreSQL database to the Heroku database.

`heroku pg:push` command doesn't work for me. Complains about lack of local `psql`, which is there. So I have decided to use pgbackups add-on for this purpose. I have run `pg_dump` locally to create a database dump and put it into the public Dropbox folder.

When I try to pull it from heroku I get the following error:

> heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE "http://file.dump"

! An error occurred and your restore did not finish.
! Please run 'heroku logs --ps pgbackups' for details.

The problem is that `heroku logs --ps pgbackups` gives me nothing. I don't see any pgbackups associated logs in the Heroku log listing.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to turn on heroku add-on logs somehow?

P.S. I am able to run `heroku pgbackups:capture` and `heroku pgbackups:restore`, but I don't see any logs either.